# Exclude Current Resource from validation check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik

I have a little function, which looks in the list of resources currently available and when you go to create and edit a resource, it checks the validity of the resource name(if it exists or not).

Here is the utility:

```
export const validateResourceName = value =>
  listResources({ once: true }).then(({ data }) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.find(resourceData => resourceData.name === value)) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
      throw 'Resource already exists';
    }
  });
```

Now, I want this to be executed only on `ADD_RESOURCE`. On `EDIT_RESOURCE`, it should throw this error without checking for the current resource name being edited. `Allowing to edit a resource without changing name`.

So I created another function, which in return called in my components validation props instead of the regular one.

```
export const validateNonCurrentResourcepName = (value, currentResource) =>
  listResources({ once: true }).then(({ data }) => {
    if (
      Array.isArray(data) &&
      data.find(resourceData => resourceData.name === value) &&
      data.map(resourceData => resourceData.name === currentResource)
    ) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
      throw 'Resource already exists';
    }
  });
```

And I ma calling it like that:

```
const debouncedValidateNonCurrentResourceName = debounce(validateNonCurrentResourceName, 250);

validate={inEditMode ? debouncedValidateResourceName : debouncedValidateNonCurrentResourceName}
```

But it is not working. Also, when I am calling the component, I am passing botht he `inEditMode`, and the `currentResource` as well. What am I doing wrong here..??

Comment: typo in validateNonCurrentResourcepName ? there's a p before Name

Comment: No, it is not that. I just typed it here. Typo doesn't exist. Even if it existed, I import and autocomplete my functions, so It would be the same everywhere.

Comment: `value` won't be changed on name edit? `find` will fail? prepare [mcve]?